# discord.js message.channel is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to make my bot delete messages in a specific channel that are not images.

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
  let channel = client.channels.get(`642417479708049418`);
  if(!message.channel(channel)) {
    return
  } else {
  if(message.embeds.length > 0) {
    return
  } else {
    message.delete();
    message.channel.send("images only");
  }
}
});
```

the error says that message.channel is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in `!message.channel(channel)`, to verify if the channel is the one you want it to be, since you already have the channel variable, just compare the two ids, you should also add a check to see if the message is coming from a bot or not, so that the bot doesn't end up in a loop of deleting its own messages:

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;

    let channel = client.channels.get(`642417479708049418`);
    if (message.channel.id != channel.id) {
        return
    } else {
        if (message.embeds.length > 0) {
            return
        } else {
            message.channel.send("images only");
            message.delete();
        }
    }
});
```

Also when you delete the message in `message.delete();` be sure to send the response you want to send first so do it in this order:

```
message.channel.send("images only");
message.delete();
```

Comment: problem with removing that is the bot wont know the 1 channel that i want this to work in

Comment: So you want the code to only run in one specific channel right?

Comment: yeah. the channel with ID variable

Comment: I've added a new piece of code, see if it works for you

Comment: using that, it went in a loop of sending the message and deleting it

Comment: That's becouse the bot is reacting to the messages that it is sending, check if the message came from a bot at the top of your event like so `if (message.author.bot) return;`

Comment: Good to know! hope you finish what you are working on now!